# IT support: Tickets and visit-report software

Tags: reporting, support-tracker

The ticket part I guess is pretty straightforward, so I'll try to explain the second:

I recently started to work with a small company: We manage the support for a few different enterprises. When we answer to issues that need us to go phisically to the place for the repairs, we charge per time. So we need a way to Report that visit to our client's enterprise manager/director/boss to justify the charge at the end of the month.

Right now we are doing it with a paper report we fill on the spot and make two copies, one is signed by the manager/director/boss and we keep it as proof of compilance with the service provided.

But I feel this way is slow and wastes paper, and I was wondering if we couldn't simply have a report software that would let us do it digitaly, and then maybe have the manager/boss sign in a tablet or phone. And by the end of each month send them all.

It doesn't need to be the same software performing both tasks. In price limit, I would prefer a free one (and open source too). In regards to OS, well it could be web based or need to run in Windows (as most of our clients run it).

Comment: Must it be the same software you use for ticketing, or could it be a separate one? What OS should it run on, what's the price limit? I could e.g. think of a [Time Tracking](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_timetracking) app. Some can also be used with triggers like NFC or Barcodes – so if your customer would have a specific tag you could use that to "pseudo-sign" your presence. At least one of them even supports having the client sign the report on your device's screen ;)

Comment: It doesn't need to be the same software.  In price limit, I would prefer a free one (and open source too). In regards to OS, well it could be web based or need to run in Windows (most of our clients run it)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've integrated that with your question. Afraid the solution I had in mind won't fit then (it's for Android and not free; if you're curious, you can find it by the name "Xpert Timer" in above linked list; they have a Windows companion for it, but I haven't tested it as I use Linux solely). Good luck then!